# c++ and SDL- Access violation error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl

I need your help. All day Im trying to figure out why I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVnqi.png), but nothing comes to my mind. The thing that I want my program to do is to take a png image and slice it to tiles, that i could use later for making a map. 
So, anyone could help me with this error?

```
#include "SDL.h"  
#include "SDL_image.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDLmain.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL_image.lib")

    int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {


    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);


    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF);

    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    SDL_Surface *mapTileSet;
    mapTileSet = IMG_Load("map.png");

    SDL_Surface *myTiles[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        myTiles[i] = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, 32, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {   
             int slice_x = x * 32;    
             int slice_y = y * 32;    

             SDL_Rect srcRect;    
             srcRect.x = slice_x;    
             srcRect.y = slice_y;    
             srcRect.w = 32;   
             srcRect.h = 32;    
             SDL_Rect dstRect;    
             dstRect.x = 0;    
             dstRect.y = 0;  

             int i =  x + y * 4;
             SDL_BlitSurface(mapTileSet, &srcRect, myTiles[i], &dstRect);
        }
    }

    SDL_BlitSurface(myTiles[0], 0, screen, 0);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    SDL_Delay(10000);


    IMG_Quit();

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Debug log:

```
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Rokas\Desktop\The Game\The Game\Debug\project.exe', Symbols loaded.
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Rokas\Desktop\The Game\The Game\SDL.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Rokas\Desktop\The Game\The Game\SDL_image.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll'
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll'
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KBDUS.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KBDUS.DLL'
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KBDUS.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KBDUS.DLL'
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dsound.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dinput.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hid.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Rokas\Desktop\The Game\The Game\libpng15-15.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'project.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Rokas\Desktop\The Game\The Game\zlib1.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
First-chance exception at 0x681247e3 in project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccf8.
Unhandled exception at 0x681247e3 in project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccf8.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xd94) has exited with code -805306369 (0xcfffffff).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x12f8) has exited with code -805306369 (0xcfffffff).
The program '[3568] project.exe: Native' has exited with code -805306369 (0xcfffffff).
```

Comment: Set breakpoint on line with `SDL_Init`, press F5 to start debugging and then press F10 / F11 go through your code till you find the line that causes the crash. When you find it you will probably realize what's going on and why you are accessing memory that you shouldn't access.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in that post.
when I edit line
SDL_BlitSurface(mapTileSet, &srcRect, myTiles[i], &dstRect);
        }
and replace myTiles[i] index with 0, it dispalys what i need.. So now I think i know, where the problem is. thank you for your debbuging advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating tiles like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    myTiles[i] = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE | SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, 32, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Where i will equal 0, 1, and 2

But accessing them like this:

```
int i =  x + y * 4;
    SDL_BlitSurface(mapTileSet, &srcRect, myTiles[i], &dstRect);
```

Where x and y will each be 0, 1, and 2. Once y is greater than 0 you will be accessing invalid data.

In general, the i = x+y*4 statement seems malformed with respect to the containing loops as it will generate the sequence {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10} which omits elements 3 and 7.